# How do I update things in Android Studio when there's a black line through the checkbox?

Tags: android, google-play-services, updates

I'm trying to update the Google Play Services for my app, but the checkbox has a black line through it.  When I click it and then click Apply, nothing happens.  I have attached an image of the problem.

[image: this is the image]

Answer (score 0):

You can update it by launching the Standalone SDK Manager.

[image]